# Is index state mean to be an initiale state in Ember.Router?

Tags: ember.js

I followed the example given in ember application stucture guide http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/ in order to understand how it works. In this example we have three main states : index, posts and post. When running the application, I got what I expected : the initial state is `index` and it transits directly to `posts`. But when I want to see individual post with `showPost` action, the router doesn't go to  `post.index` and get stuck in `root.post` or the expected path should be `root.post.comments`.
Is it a bug or something that I missed ?

There is an associated jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jrabary/bX5hb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here less or more working jsfiddle for the http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/ routing guide.

http://jsfiddle.net/dq2fE/